# .htcaccess rules not working properly

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I encountered a small issue while trying to make my site redirect all http requests to https. Before I start, however, I should warn you that I'm rather new to this, so please show mercy ;)
 Here's my htcaccess file:

```
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

  RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php

  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^.*$ https://nordicraft.net/%{REQUEST_URI} [NC]
```

To start off, I'm runing my site on shared hosting, and the everything to the first RewriteRule was in the file the first time I opened it. I have no idea what the -d and -f conditions mean or what are they supposed to do, so I left them untouched. The only things I added were the last RewriteCond and RewriteRule.
Now, the issue is, it works as intended ONLY when accessing the main page, that is, simply entering nordicraft.net in the address bar. It redirects me to the https version, as intended. Also, it does the same thing if I explicitly try to access the index.php file. However, if I try accessing any other website feature, like the forums, it redirects me to `https://${REQUESt_URI}`. In  my case, `https://forum`. You can view the site in real time at http://nordicraft.net.
Any ideas what is causing this, or possible fixes? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://nordicraft.net%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you for the kind answer, however I managed to solve that on my own. Apparently, I was so tired that I didn't realize I hadn't been using that rule I pasted here, rather an older one which had the problem. I was also confused by the fact that I was still seeing that issue with the forum redirect even after completely removing the additional rules from the file, but I finally realized that clearing my browser cache solved the forums redirect issue, and then using my old set of rules did the trick. Thank you anyways!